# angular-chart.js - chart height not working on iOS but works fine on Android and Web

Tags: ios, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) in my project to draw `chart-doughnut` with `ionic`. What I am doing here is setting chart height from controller code. The height I am setting is based on screen size. It is working perfectly fine on Android and Web but on iOS it is not working. Below is my code:

HTML code:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="data" height="{{height_chart}}" chart-colors="colors" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"></canvas>
```

Javascript code:

```
  if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
    $scope.height_chart = window.innerHeight * 0.5;
  }
  $scope.colors = ['#3973ac', '#d9e6f2'];
  $scope.options = {
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    hover: {
      mode: null
    },
    elements: {
      arc: {
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    }
  };
```

I am not able to figure out the problem. Any pointer will be highly appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason why it happened but it is working fine on `iOS real device`. Issue can be reproduce only on `simulator`. Maybe there is some rendering issue in simulator.